# How to implement PRG pattern and still use Ajax post response in asp mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post

Our MVC Controllers inherit from a custom controller that removes the response (for PRG pattern):

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod != @"GET")
    {
        Response.Clear();
    }
}
```

On the client side, I am doing a simple save to the database:

```
        var success = function (result) {
             showNotification(result.Message, 'success', 3000);
             hrp.load();
        }


        var inputArray = $(hoursForm + ' [name], ' + hoursFormId);
        postAjaxArrayData('RoundingPolicies/SaveHoursRoundingPolicy', inputArray, success);
```

Which makes it to the controller fine, does the save, but since we are clearing out the response, the success() is not getting the result back from:

```
public void SaveHoursRoundingPolicy(HoursRoundingPolicyViewModel hoursRoundingPolicyViewModel) {

   // Save

    var json = new {
        hoursRoundingPolicyViewModel.RoundingPolicyId,
        hoursRoundingPolicyViewModel.Name,
        Message = String.Format("Successfully Saved - ({0}) {1}", hoursRoundingPolicyViewModel.RoundingPolicyId, hoursRoundingPolicyViewModel.Name)
    };
    return Json(json);
}
```

How can we still implement the PRG pattern (by clearing the response on POSTs) but still get results back from Ajax POSTs?  Can I distinguish between the two in OnResultExecuted()?

I would imagine this would be a fairly common scenario by anyone using PRG pattern with MVC, any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you clearing the response? That's not really part of PRG... at least not in my experience.

In my experience using PRG, you accept the post, when/if it's successful you simply redirect to another action, which causes the GET, no need to clear the response.

Following the above pattern would still allow your AJAX posts to work like a normal post

```
// Simple implementation of PRG    
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)
public ActionResult Something(int value) {
   return RedirectToAction("SomethingElse");
}

public ActionResult SomethingElse() {
   return View();
}

// Simple implementation of standard post
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)
public ActionResult SomethingAjax(int value) {
   return Json(value);
}
```

**EDITED for filterContext.Result Comparison**
This should check the Action's return type and not apply the Response.Clear() to the Response when it's a JsonResult

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod != @"GET" && !(filterContext.Result is JsonResult))
    {
        Response.Clear();
    }
}

// Simple implementation of standard post
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)
public JsonResult SomethingAjax(int value) {
   return Json(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony, so as long as we redirect on the ActionResults, we are fine returning a response for any JSON type request/responses?  We are safe from duplicate submits, refreshes, etc?  I was thinking the same thought, but wanted to hear what others thought...

Comment: Yes, because once the redirect occurs, it is requesting a GET from the redirected Action. I suppose  as another alternative, you could do JsonResult return type and possibly handle that in your OnResultExecuted (don't have any code example for that, but can work on something if you'd like to see it) and you could not do the clear there (if you're dead-set on using the Response.Clear)

Comment: actually added the code to check the Action Result type, it was easier than I thought